# How can I read a resource file located in the same module from where it read with python importlib resources?

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging, python-importlib

I have a folder structure resembling the following.

```
.
├── data
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── fish.csv
└── fish_service.py
```

I would like to access my fish list from `fish_service.py`, by importing them from `data` with something like `from .data import all_fish`, where `all_fish` is a list of what's in the csv.

I found that I can read my csv with `importlib.resources` from `__init__.py` using the following

```
import csv
from importlib.resources import files

from .. import data

all_fish = []
with files(data).joinpath("fish.csv").open() as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for fish in item_reader:
        all_fish.append(fish)
```

However, I dislike the fact that I need to go back to the parent folder to import `data`, and PyCharm does not seem to like it either.

This solution does work, but is there a better way to import my resource from the same module I'm currently in?

Comment: You should not need `from .. import data`, but rather `from . import data` or simply `import data`. It does not make sense according to the directory structure you are showing in your question. Maybe we are missing some (hidden) details here? -- How do you start the program?

Comment: All this is part of a much larger structure, but I do not under the impression that it's relevant here. What you might be missing is that the `csv` is read from `__init__.py` and not `fish_service.py`. I tried to make it clearer in the question.

Comment: I see, so you want a reference to the current package. Maybe `importlib.resources.files(__package__)`, although I think I would rather recommend using the absolute name `importlib.resources.files('mypackage.data')`.

Comment: It do work with `__package__`, thanks!